# How can I get the business page icon from instagram using API?

Tags: instagram-api

I need to get the business icon from it's instagram account, but I didn't found something like that in documentation, I only found how to get the business's media.

Is it possible to catch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Page Information, there's a section called "Edge" and in it there is a attribute called "picture"